# Using <h3> within <ol> with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<ol ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
       <h3 ng-bind-html="item.title"></h3>
       <li ng-repeat="description in item.items" ng-bind-html="description">  </li>
</ol>
```

This is how it is rendered on screen:

```
**Title1**
   1. Desciption1
   2. Description2
**Title2**
   1. Description1
```

But as per the HTML standards, `ol` should only contain `li`, not `h3`.

Any idea how we can achieve this?

Comment: is it critical for you to use exactly h3 tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just wrap this construction in one more block? Placing `h3` tag in this case will be correct enough.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
    <h3 ng-bind-html="item.title"></h3>
    <ol>
          <li ng-repeat="description in item.items" ng-bind-html="description"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

In other case, if you would like to create list of lists and you really want to use `<ol>` for both you can do in the next way:

```
<ol ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
    <li>
        <h3 ng-bind-html="item.title"></h3>
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="description in item.items" ng-bind-html="description"></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

In this way you have nested lists, but all h3 tags are inside the `li` tag, not inside the `ol`directly. That is fine. HTML syntax rules allow headings tags in the `li` elements. I would prefer to use first variant, because it looks clearer and more understandable.
But second one also is a valid HTML structure according to [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea):

[image]

Comment: The first version, being invalid HTML, automatically rules that out as a good answer.

Comment: The first version is valid HTML, not sure what Rob is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use div inside li tag

as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="description in item.items">
<div>
    <h3 ng-bind-html="item.title"></h3>
    <div ng-bind-html="description"></div>
</div></li>
```